# Java Read data from Barcode Scanner USB using USB util

Tags: java, android, usb, barcode-scanner

I am trying to connect to read from a USB connected Barcode reader using Java USB Utils in android. I was able to detect the USB and also the manufacturer details but was not able to read the barcode string. I was using the USB Util to Hex String while reading the bytes from the barcode reader. (http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/jdoc/javax/usb/util/UsbUtil.html#toHexString(byte))

However, the result of above operation is a random string and not the original barcode scanned. Can someone help me to convert the string into the required valid format?  I believe I was able to scan the barcode and was able to get the value but the format of the data is not decimal and may be is a Hex String as mentioned above. How can I convert this string captured to the required decimal format?

Sample Code Used:

```
public class HighCardReader throws UsbException
{

    StringBuffer output;
    super();
    this.listener = new Vector();
    super.addListener(new CardObserver(){
        public void readByte(byte[] data) {
            /** 
             * parse the data. */
            output= new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
            {
                output.append(UsbUtil.toHexString(data[i]));

            }

            synchronized (listener) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listener.size(); i++) {
                    if (listener.get(i) instanceof CardObserver) {
                        CardObserver lis = (CardObserver) listener.get(i);

                        /**  
                         *  convert string data into byte array.*/
                        System.out.println("output is = " + output.toString());
                        byte[] b = output.toString().getBytes();

                        output= new StringBuffer();
                        lis.readByte(b);

                        //The updating interval of the display is 1 second.
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

}

I have tried to convert the received data byte array to target string using the three sample codes but neither worked:

**Try1:**

```
 char[] charBuffer = new String(data, Charset.forName("US-ASCII")).toCharArray();
```

**Try 2:**

```
byte[] decodeByteArray  = Base64.decodeBase64(data); 
String dataString  = new String(decodeByteArray);
```

**Try 3:**

```
String dataString=new String(data);
```

I have very little knowledge on the USB Hid conversion though barcode reader.

Comment: Did you figure it out please? I need some help on that too. I was thinking if you can provide some help. Thanks